# using ENI in autoscaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have created 3 eni and in my cloud formation template I want to use the ip from the eni in  auto scaling group .I cannot use elastic ip due to org constraints.I am trying to find a way to keep my ip same every time ec2 spins up .But I did not find a way to attach eni to ASG?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot attach an ENI to an autoscaling group.  They need to be attached to instances, and AWS does not provide a direct way to attach from a pool of ENIs to a newly spawned instance in an autoscaling group.

AWS Lambda is a good way to manage something a case like this, although you must provide the code yourself.  Set up a Lambda function to subscribe to autoscaling events (via SNS) from the autoscaling group, and to attach an unattached ENI to a newly-created instance.